# Move answers on duplicate questions to the main question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When a question is marked as duplicate, why not remove/delete/hide the answers on that question, and add/show them on the main question?

Then all the answers are in a single place and can compete for top spot.

Comment: This happens with valuable duplicates, I think; moderators can merge them.

Comment: Depending on how a question is phrased will also affect how the answer is presented. It's possible that an answer to another question will not logically "fit" under another question, even though the underlying information could be relevant.

Comment: [8512](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1159710) posts were involved in merges, either as destination or source.

Comment: It's probably not done automatically because for common dupe targets you'd end up with hundreds of quasi-duplicate FGIW answers entered before the dupes were closed clogging up the main question.

Answer (score 6):

No, we don't need an automatic way of it to happen. There is already a manual way (merge) to handle rare cases when both questions have good answers and all answers make sense on the target of the duplicate.

In most cases more narrow questions closed as duplicate of a broader question. As result it is unlikely specific answers from the duplicate will actually completely answer the target question. Even if questions are close enough to have compatible answers usually newer one has simplified / lower quality answers that either repeat once one the target or just not add any value and hence no point moving to target.