# Can we reverse the duplicate direction on these two questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

The question [I am trying to edit text on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011931/i-am-trying-to-edit-text-on-canvas) has objectively better answers than the duplicate target [HTML5 Canvas Text Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814353).

The most upvoted answer on the closed question explains how `fillText` works, and then goes through examples of how to make editable text work, and includes sample code.

The answers on the duplicate target are mostly explaining how it's not possible or suggesting outdated libraries. They don't go into much detail as to why, or how to work around this limitation.

Can the duplicate direction be reversed?

Comment: Isn't there a javascript chat, where you could discuss that with the js expert peers first.

Comment: @πάντα if you think it needs discussing? I already posted there but it's a very quiet chat at the best of times.

Comment: In that case the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) might still be a better place to discuss that than here, unless you better clarify the facts about those 2 posts, and what makes one superior over the other.

Comment: @πάντα I've added details here

Comment: I agree the answers are (much) better. But I don't really think it is worth the effort to do the reversal, the fact that they're linked is enough. Let me put it differently: if this is important enough that it needs resolving, the site should have a dedicated feature for it that does not involve having to go to meta for each and every case of wrong linkage that you find.

Comment: @gimby gold badge tag users can do it, from what I've heard.

Comment: [Mods can also merge the answers if it's really necessary.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391720/476716)

Comment: @Gimby I don't know for the others, but when I see a duplicate tag, my instincts tell me to forget the duplicated one and have a look at the "original" question.

Comment: Really odd that two of the people who voted Leave Open on the close review also voted Leave Closed on the reopen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have taken a look at this and provided some badly needed edits to your preferred target, both to the question and to the answer. Some changes were also needed to make it a suitable duplicate target for the other question.

Since both questions were tagged with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), I was able to use my gold badge powers to reverse the direction of the duplicate.

Comment: That's great, I really appreciate the effort you put into improving the question and answer.